# How to install Jenkins inside of Google App Engine using Terraform?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to find how to setup Jenkins on Google App Engine and also using Terraform. Can anyone suggest any documentation or tutorial on that? Cant find any in net.

Comment: You should probably look in the Marketplace for "Jenkins" and it will launch a ready-to-use Jenkins instance for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would  suggest looking into Google Compute engine instead of Google App Engine, since App Engine Flex it is a limited instance of Compute engine and you will have a lot more trouble doing so.

Given the two approaches I will list the docs and tutorial to follow.

For any approach read this docs:

1. [Terraform GCP examples](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/tree/master/examples)
2. [Change Log of GCP Terraform Provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
3. [GCP Terraform provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/index.html)
4. [Managing GCP projects with Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform)

If you go for the App Engine approach you could check the following docs:

1. [Create an App Engine instance with Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/app_engine_application.html).
2. [CI/CD with Containers/jenkis/Terraform](https://medium.com/@timhberry/terraform-pipelines-in-jenkins-47267129ff06)

If you go for the Compute Engine approach you could check the following docs:

1. [Getting started with Terraform on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-on-gcp-with-terraform)
2. [Complete GCP environment with Terraform](https://medium.com/slalom-technology/a-complete-gcp-environment-with-terraform-c087190366f0)
3. [Terraform with Jenkins and GCP](https://medium.com/@pb8226/running-terraform-with-jenkins-pipelines-f29a8cb861d4)

Hope it's useful.